# Echo User Name from User with most comments of today?

Tags: wp-query

Without the date - I'm trying to integrate - the code is working: outputting the user with the most comments. But currently I try to get the user with **most comments of today** but that does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', time() + 86400);
    $where = 'WHERE comment_date >= %s  AND comment_date < %s AND user_id <> 0';
    $comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
    {$where}
    GROUP BY user_id
    ", object);
    foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
    $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
    echo 'http://fragmatisch.de/profil/' . $user->display_name .  '
    ';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query instead to select comments count grouped by user id.

```
  SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM wp_comments WHERE DATE(comment_date) = CURDATE() AND user_id <> 0 GROUP BY user_id
```

by the way, in your where variable you should use $wpdb->prepare() to assign values with variables ( if you are going to use it in future )

```
  $where = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE comment_date >= %s  AND comment_date < %s AND user_id <> 0', $today, $tomorrow );
```

This code should work for you:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $where = 'WHERE DATE(comment_date) = CURDATE() AND user_id <> 0';
 $sql = "SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM {$wpdb->comments} {$where} GROUP BY user_id";
 $comment_count = $wpdb->get_results($sql, "ARRAY_A");
 if( !empty( $comment_count ) ) {
   foreach ( $comment_count as $count ) {
     $user = get_userdata($count['user_id']); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url().'/author/' . $user->data->user_login; ?>"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></a><?php
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is a better answer. Even better would be `$where = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE comment_date >= %s  AND comment_date < %s AND user_id <> 0', $today, $tomorrow );`

Comment: Is this the right implementation? :

`<?php
global $wpdb;

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', time() + 86400);
$where = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE comment_date >= %s AND comment_date < %s AND user_id <> 0', $today, $tomorrow );
 $comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
    {$where}
    GROUP BY user_id
    ", object);
foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
$user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
echo 'http://fragmatisch.de/profil/' . $user->display_name .  '
';
}
?>`

Comment: Eric Holmes, thanks for suggesting $wpdb->prepare..!!

Comment: @sven Thx alot but I need to echo the user_name to complete the url. This php is wrapped in a <a href=" ... php ..."></a> code. Somehow it's not working. :(

Comment: check the update and see if it works for you, it'll echo username as <a href="profile link">User display name</a>

Comment: @sven My code should look like this:

<a href=" ... php to get name ... "> <some divs which should be linked> </a>

Comment: that is a minor change you can make it yourself, just replace the User display name with your div code

Comment: Seems that it does not work...

Comment: But thx for trying, I will give you some reputation (=

Comment: Whats not working, you undrestand that by replacing display name, I meant remove the PHP code from there and put your div and by the way you are not making clear what is your actual requirement, how you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `where` condition variable with this:

```
$where = 'WHERE comment_date >= "' . $today . '" AND comment_date < "' . $tomorrow . '" AND user_id <> 0';
```

You don't use your `$today` and `$tomorrow` variables.

Comment: This way does not work somehow.